# ReactJS read malformed JSON file

Tags: json, reactjs

Currently trying to learn how to use reactJS and I'm trying to read in a malformed json file.

EG

```
{
    Item : "text",
    Desc : "example"
}
```

Now my understanding is that typically I can use

```
import data from "data.json"
```

which would build an object I could use, however that won't work with the malformed json.

I think that my solution would be to read the file as one big string, use regex to clean the json, and then attempt to parse it, but I'm not really sure how to go about reading the file in.

Comment: This is not really related to React, more of a general JavaScript question. Are you trying to load that data file in the browsers, or in the backend, i.e. using Node.js?

Comment: I'm running Node for development, but aim to build to static files